# Helper class not found

Tags: magento, admin

I'm trying to develop an extension that would add a form on the Admin side of Magento, but, for some reason, I can't seem to be able to even get Magento Administration to load when my module is installed. I'm at the very beginning of the development, and I'm stuck on an error that has been reported several times on StackOverflow. Unfortunately, none of the answers seem to help in my case.

The error I get is *Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Mycompany_Logviewer_Helper_Data' not found in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\magento\app\Mage.php on line 546*. That should mean that Magento can't find the helper class, but it's there and its name matches the one it's looking for (except for the "Mage_" at the beginning, that I never used in any other extension anyway).

**Update 2012/07/29**
The error occurs as soon as I log in into Magento Admin. When I click "Login", all I get is an error page, nothing is rendered.

Here's the content of all the files I have so far.

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mycompany_Logviewer>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Mycompany_Logviewer>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <models>
            <logviewer>
                <class>Mycompany_Logviewer_Model</class>
            </logviewer>
        </models>
        <blocks>
            <logviewer>
                <class>Mycompany_Logviewer_Block</class>
            </logviewer>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <logviewer>
                <class>Mycompany_Logviewer_Helper</class>
            </logviewer>
        </helpers>
    </global>

    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <mycompany_logviewer after="Mage_Adminhtml">Mycompany_Logviewer_Adminhtml</mycompany_logviewer>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>

    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <mycompany translate="title" module="mycompany_logviewer">
                <title>Mycompany</title>
                <sort_order>90</sort_order>
                <children>
                    <form translate="title" module="mycompany_logviewer">
                        <title>Form</title>
                        <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                        <action>adminhtml/logviewer</action>
                    </form>
                </children>
            </mycompany>
        </menu>

        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <mycompany>
                            <title>Mycompany</title>
                            <sort_order>90</sort_order>
                            <children>
                                <form>
                                    <title>Form</title>
                                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                                </form>
                            </children>
                        </mycompany>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

**Data.php (Helper)**

```
class Mycompany_Logviewer_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

**LogviewerController.php (Controller)**

```
class Mycompany_Logviewer_Adminhtml_LogviewerController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    /**
    * View form action
    */
    public function indexAction() {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_setActiveMenu('Mycompany/form');
        $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('Mycompany_Logviewer')->__('Form'), Mage::helper('Mycompany_Logviewer')->__('Form'));
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    /**
    * Check allow or not access to ths page
    *
    * @return bool - is allowed to access this menu
    */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('Mycompany/form');
    }
}
```

**Mycompany_Logviewer.xml (configuration file)**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mycompany_Logviewer>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Mycompany_Logviewer>
    </modules>
</config>
```

All the above have been copied from an [example I found online](http://turnkeye.com/blog/magento-admin-form/#more-1789), I just replaced the Namespace and the Module name with *Mycompany* and *Logviewer*, respectively. I'm pretty sure it's something obvious I forgot, but I can't figure out what it could be. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing that jumps out is that you are registering a module with the name of  `Procedo_Logviewer` - when in fact it should be `Mycompany_Logviewer`

So, `Mycompany_Logviewer.xml` should be as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mycompany_Logviewer>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Mycompany_Logviewer>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Clear cache after changing

**EDIT**

Looking more closely at your controller, I can also see that you are calling your helper like so:

```
Mage::helper('Mycompany_Logviewer')
```

You should be calling your helper like this instead:

```
Mage::helper('logviewer')
```

**EDIT 2**

Another issue is present in your config.xml

```
module="mycompany_logviewer"
```

Should be

```
module="logviewer"
```

This correlates to the helper node you declared in your xml i.e.

```
<helpers>
    <logviewer>
        <class>Mycompany_Logviewer_Helper</class>
    </logviewer>
</helpers>
```

Comment: Thanks Drew. I changed the declaration, but I still get the same error. I'm updating the question to reflect the changes.

Comment: About the cache, it's all disabled, so I won't have to clear it every time I change something. Thanks anyway for the tip. :)

Comment: Thanks Drew. I tried your suggestion, but it still doesn't work. To be clearer, the error appears as soon as I log in into Magento Admin Panel. I haven't invoked the Controller at that stage, therefore the code in it should be irrelevant. As soon as I click "log in", I get the error.

Comment: There are further issues in your config.xml i have pointed out

Comment: A-ha! That did it! The menu section was the culprit. I changed `<mycompany translate="title" module="mycompany_logviewer">` to `<mycompany translate="title" module="logviewer">` and now I can log in and see the menu entry. Thing is, the example I copied clearly stated `<turnkeye translate="title" module="turnkeye_adminform">`, I simply replaced the words. I also checked another example, which was giving me exactly the same error, and its menu section was similar: `<myexercise translate="title" module="myexercise_myform">`. I can understand if one was wrong, but both of them?

Comment: Cool - glad its working for you :)  Magento will be much more enjoyable if you spend the time to learn it properly - copying and pasting from tutorials might seem like a quick fix at times but is going to cause you problems in the long run :)  If in doubt, look at how the core code is doing something - there is almost always an example of what you need to achieve somewhere in the core code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14598/discussion-between-diego-and-drew-hunter)

Comment: Thank the lord for your answer, @Diego. Your tip in the comments I had to expand to read solved a 4 hour quest to install a simple admin menu item.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem. Solution was putting company name in  like this:

```
<helpers>
    <Mycompany_Logviewer>
        <class>Mycompany_Logviewer_Helper</class>
    </Mycompany_Logviewer>
</helpers>
```

---

```
$myHelper= Mage::helper('Mycompany_Logviewer');
```